# How to get previous 6 months data, group by each month starting with current month in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is my table:(DATE is in TIMESTAMP datatype...here i mentioned in DATE)

```
DATE(DD/MM/YYYY)             VALUE
10/05/2020                    3
20/05/2020                    7
08/04/2020                    12
10/04/2020                    28
15/03/2020                    13
08/02/2020                    12
10/01/2020                    28
15/12/2019                    13
21/12/2019                    18
12/11/2019                    17
```

I want to get

```
MONTH             TOTAL
05/2020            10
04/2020            40
03/2020            13
02/2020            12
01/2020            28
12/2019            31
```

I should get only till DEC i.e. 6 mnths from today.....Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: My DATE col is of type TIMESTAMP----
select to_date(to_char(date,'dd/mon/yyyy'), 'yyyy/mon') month,
        sum(value) total
  from table
  where date>= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6)
  group by to_date(to_char(date,'dd/mon/yyyy'), 'yyyy/mon')
 order by month desc;

Comment: Please edit your question to include it. What you tried should always be in the body of your questions. Also don't forget to format your code and don't hesitate to check the "preview" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SQL> with test (datum, value) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select timestamp '2020-05-10 00:00:00.000',  3 from dual union all
  4     select timestamp '2020-05-20 00:00:00.000',  7 from dual union all
  5     select timestamp '2020-04-08 00:00:00.000', 12 from dual union all
  6     select timestamp '2020-04-10 00:00:00.000', 28 from dual union all
  7     select timestamp '2020-03-15 00:00:00.000', 13 from dual union all
  8     select timestamp '2020-02-08 00:00:00.000', 12 from dual union all
  9     select timestamp '2020-01-10 00:00:00.000', 28 from dual union all
 10     select timestamp '2019-12-15 00:00:00.000', 13 from dual union all
 11     select timestamp '2019-12-21 00:00:00.000', 18 from dual union all
 12     select timestamp '2019-11-12 00:00:00.000', 17 from dual
 13    )
 14  -- query you need
 15  select to_char(datum, 'yyyy/mm') month,
 16         sum(value) total
 17  from test
 18  where datum >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6)
 19  group by to_char(datum, 'yyyy/mm')
 20  order by month desc;

MONTH        TOTAL
------- ----------
2020/05         10
2020/04         40
2020/03         13
2020/02         12
2020/01         28
2019/12         31

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I have date coulmn of type TIMESTAMP. Abve query is working for DATE type @Littlefoot

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with TIMESTAMP? Did you try it? What happened? Besides, how is anyone supposed what you have if you don't say it while posting the question?

Comment: It is not for me; I edited the answer and used TIMESTAMPs. Works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
select
    to_char(date, 'MM-YYYY') as months,
    sum(value) as total 
from myTable
where date > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '6' MONTH
group by
    to_char(date, 'MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: This does not answer the "6 months from today" part

Comment: @Rafalon try now